# Helgen - guide disappeared

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Apparently I've spent too much time exploring the dungeon etc in Helgen Keep and my guy, the one who kept telling me to follow him, has vanished. How do I find him again?

Comment: Just to clarify, have you already left the cave and are now in the world-proper?

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside the cave and have killed all the bad guys, just keep walking around, he'll start talking to you again if you get close enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the cave/zone, the people that are with you normally follow you through. This works even if they are far away.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about him, you won't find him in the rest of the dungeon if he's gone, but:

> If you gone ahead of the guy you go with in Helgen, and you didn't follow him but went through the dungeon without him, he'll be outside the exit when you get to the part when you talk to a specific person to report the dragon attack.